# Edit booking duration for multiple products on WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've recently imported over 200 products into my system using the CSV Import Suite but, as I could see, I cannot edit the booking duration nor the product availability automatically. Meaning that I would have to go to each product individually if I want to set a proper booking duration.

Is there a way to edit by one (or any) of the options below?

- Change the default booking settings. If possible, where?
- Using a simple `UPDATE` query in the database. If possible, which table?
- Add extra fields in the CSV file. If possible, which fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found all the properties I needed in the DB and created a script to update. See the code below in case someone needs. Remember to adapt to your needs.

```
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_base_cost', '' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_calendar_display_mode', 'always_visible' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_duration_type', 'fixed' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_duration', 21 FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_duration_unit', 'day' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_user_can_cancel', 'yes' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_cancel_limit', 8 FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_cancel_limit_unit', 'day' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_min_date', 2 FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_min_date_unit', 'week' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_buffer_period', 8 FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_review_count', 0 FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_cost', '' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_display_cost', '' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_min_duration', 1 FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_max_duration', 1 FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_enable_range_picker', 'no' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_qty', 1 FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_has_persons', 'no' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_person_qty_multiplier', 'no' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_person_cost_multiplier', 'no' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_min_persons_group', 1 FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_max_persons_group', '' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_has_person_types', 'no' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_has_resources', 'no' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_resources_assignment', 'customer' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_max_date', 12 FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_max_date_unit', 'month' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_first_block_time', '' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_requires_confirmation', 'no' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_default_date_availability', 'available' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_check_availability_against', '' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_resouce_label', '' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_availability', 'a:0:{}' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_booking_pricing', 'a:0:{}' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_memberships_product_viewing_restricted_message', '' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_memberships_use_custom_product_viewing_restricted_message', 'no' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_memberships_product_purchasing_restricted_message', '' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_memberships_use_custom_product_purchasing_restricted_message', 'no' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_memberships_force_public', 'no' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
REPLACE INTO `db_site`.one_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) (SELECT ID, '_wc_memberships_exclude_discounts', 'no' FROM `db_site`.one_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
```

*Not the best SQL script I've created but it does the job* :)